# Why can't my iPhone sync with my hp laptop and how can I fix it?

Tags: windows, iphone

I have an iPhone 4s and I'm connecting it to my HP computer with Windows 8.1 OS. I don't have iTunes on it yet. When I connect it syncs then un syncs very fast almost as if my laptop is rejecting it. The Lightning works because when I connect it to a charger socket it charges perfectly. The USB port works because I can insert flash.

Are there any drivers needed and do I have to download them? Is it mandatory to install iTunes?

Comment: Easy fix - get iTunes. It contains the drivers necessary for the iPhone to connect.

Comment: What do you want to do with the iPhone when conected? Just charge it? Download pictures? Manage media?

Comment: @Tetsujin sorry for the wait but even if I downloaded iTunes ( 12.2.2.25 ) the computer still rejects  the iPhone what is the problem!

Comment: Rejects it? How? Does it mount & dismount repeatedly? That could be the USB not supplying sufficient power - an iPhone is not the same as a flash drive in that respect.

Comment: @Tetsujin it mounts then dismounts instantaneously and the USB works fine. What can I do about it?

Comment: other than try it on a powered external hub, or try the laptop mains powered, I'm not really sure